# Adding new datafile to tablespace but no datafile being created

Tags: oracle

I recently faced the following error:

> ORA-01688: unable to extend table RATEL.MV_IN_GPRS_SPLIT partition SYS_P54817 by 128 in tablespace RATEL" while loading data into the database.

To resolve it I am trying to add a new datafile on Oracle 11g using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE RATEL 
    ADD DATAFILE 'e:\app\oracle\oradata\rvas\RATEL141.dbf' 
    SIZE 20000M 
    AUTOEXTEND ON 
    MAXSIZE 32000M;
```

However, the query is executing endlessly and no datafile has been created.

How can I verify if the datafile has been created or not?
What would cause a datafile to not be created?

Comment: Are you on XE??

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: How long is "endlessly"? The above command needs to allocate a 20 GB file which could take minutes if your infrastructure is slow.

Comment: Its been over 4hours now.

Comment: You are aware that 11.2.0.1 is buggy as *anything*. It could be a bug that was fixed in 11.2.0.2.  Check MOS.

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but possible things to look at.

#### ALERT_.LOG (ALERT.LOG) File Specifically

Have a look at the alert.log file for your instance. It should contain lines that look a bit like this after you sent the command:

```
2022-01-07T08:37:09.455525+01:00
ALTER TABLESPACE RATEL 
  ADD DATAFILE 'e:\app\oracle\oradata\rvas\RATEL141.dbf'
  SIZE 20000M
  AUTOEXTEND ON
  MAXSIZE 32000M
2022-01-07T08:37:48.127440+01:00
```

This will be followed by an entry for completion:

```
Completed: ALTER TABLESPACE RATEL 
  ADD DATAFILE 'e:\app\oracle\oradata\rvas\RATEL141.dbf'
  SIZE 20000M
  AUTOEXTEND ON
  MAXSIZE 32000M
```

If you don't see the above lines, then the command might not have been sent and/or is waiting for some kind of acknowledgement.

#### ALERT_.LOG (ALERT.LOG) In General

After receiving the error that the tablespace had run full, are there any other entries in the alert.log file that tell you what might be failing?

#### Disk Capacity

Does the disk where you are creating the additional datafile have enough capacity for the new file?

If not, chose a different location/drive with enough capacity.